# QListWidget don't show the selected row

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I made a list in my program and a function to reorder (up/down) the rows
So i use `setCurrentRow()` to change the selected row after moving
it works well but the selection is not shown in the list

How can i do that

ps: i tried `setSelectionRectVisible(True)` but nothing happen.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.my_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.my_list.setGeometry(5,5,90,100)
        QListWidgetItem("1",self.my_list)
        QListWidgetItem("2",self.my_list)
        QListWidgetItem("3",self.my_list)
        QListWidgetItem("4",self.my_list)

        self.upButton = QPushButton("Up",self)
        self.upButton.move(100,10)
        self.upButton.clicked.connect(self.up)
        self.downButton = QPushButton("Down",self)
        self.downButton.move(100,30)
        self.downButton.clicked.connect(self.down)

    def up(self, event):
        w=self.my_list.currentRow() 
        if w > 0:
            self.my_list.insertItem(w-1, self.my_list.currentItem().text())
            self.my_list.takeItem(w+1)
            self.my_list.setCurrentRow(w-1)
            # self.my_list.setSelectionRectVisible(True)

    def down(self, event):
        w = self.my_list.currentRow() 
        if w < self.my_list.count()-1:
            self.my_list.insertItem(w+2, self.my_list.currentItem().text())
            self.my_list.takeItem(w)
            self.my_list.setCurrentRow(w+1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = MainWindow()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was creating this simple example to show and it works well with default background (grey)

So my problem is to find the name of the highlighted property to set it

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

So i found a solution in the stylesheet i have to put:

```
 QListWidget::item:selected:!active { background: #0099cc}
```

thanks